# Finding the estimator of π(1-π) from a random sample of n Bernoulli trials.

Tags: statistics, random-variables, binomial-distribution, sampling, parameter-estimation

A random sample of n independent Bernoulli trials with success probability π results in R successes. 
Derive an unbiased estimator of π (1 − π).

So, from what I understand (correct me if anything I say is wrong), R is a random variable that follows a binomial distribution. 
However, I am unsure about how to approach this question. Could someone please talk me through it?

Comment: If $T_1$ and $T_2$ are unbiased estimators of $\pi$ and $\pi^2$ respectively, then an unbiased estimator of $\pi-\pi^2$ is $T_1-T_2$. Try finding $T_1,T_2$ from $R$, which is indeed binomial$(n,\pi)$.

Answer (score 2):

We have $\frac1nX$ and $1-\frac1nX$ as unbiased estimators of $\pi$ and $1-\pi$ respectively.

This makes us wonder what we can "expect" from: $$Z:=\frac1nX\left(1-\frac1nX\right)$$

I am not saying that this random variable will do the job, but it cannot harm to find  the expectation of $Z$ (and eventually adjust).

So you could start with giving that a try.

Comment: So if I take the expected of value of Z I end up with $$E(Z):=\frac{n-1}{n}\left(\pi(1-\pi\right))$$ , so then in order to get an unbiased estimator I should multiply by $$\frac{n}{n-1}$$  i.e. $$\frac{n}{n-1}Z$$ is an unbiased estimator of $$ \pi(1-\pi)$$ ?

Comment: That is exactly the route I had in mind for you.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was very useful and now makes a lot more sense to me.

Comment: You are very welcome.